# I'm trying to put a line of text in the center, but it doesn't work

Tags: html, css

```css
.center {
    margin: auto;
    width: 50%;
    border: 3px solid black;
    padding: 10px;
}

p6 {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Here is the line:

```html
<br><p6>~~This text is centered~~</p6><br>
```

Comment: What type of element is `p6` supposed to be?

Comment: Your custom `p6` element does not have your `center` class.

Comment: Nor is `<p6>` any valid element type I am aware of-- you may have some misunderstanding regarding HTML fundamentals (or a typo).

Comment: I'm trying to go through my pre course work, so I'm just trying to scramble through this. I'm trying to separate the paragraph through the numbering. I guess that didn't make sense.

Comment: You are correct that this does not work nor make sense. You'll probably want to exercise a bit more caution learning HTML/CSS, because the browser is, by design, a very forgiving rendering environment-- it will do its best to render a usable interface, even if you feed it invalid code. This means you might be writing invalid code and not know it. With the exception of custom elements, you'll want to write the elements exactly as HTML defines them, and separate them by means of _attributes_ like `class`, `id`, or some custom data attribute. Good luck, and happy coding!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HTML5 does not define a `p6` element (it does define an [`h6`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Heading_Elements) element). You might be using a [custom element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_custom_elements), but since you don't provide the code for that, and its tag name doesn't follow the naming convention for a custom element, your browser will treat `p6` as an [unknown element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLUnknownElement).

Now, you can still use this unknown element, but by default your browser will consider it to be an [inline element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Inline_elements). If you instruct your browser to render it as a [block-level element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements), it will correctly center the text:

```css
p6 {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<br><p6>~~This text is centered~~</p6><br>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just did a simple mistake there are h1,h2,h3 .. h6 tags in html there is no p tag with number associated Just replace p6 to p in html and css both and it should work

Comment: Unfortunately, this is actually not what the user did-- if you look at their comments, they state they were trying to number their paragraphs.

Comment: you are right I just read that comment, He is trying to differentiate paragraphs with numbers.

Answer (score 0):

## Without CSS

This method may be a bit off topic on CSS, but it should help users who want to use something more simple.

(As Alexander said, `<center>` is deprecated so this is not suggested even though it still works)

You can used the HTML `<center>` element like so:

```html
<br><center><p6>~~This text is centered~~</p6></center><br>
```

## With CSS

If you want to use CSS, you can use the solution below: (Credit to @Robby Cornelissen)

```
p6 {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Also note that P6 doesn't exist, the author was trying to number his paragraphs.
Have a great day!

Comment: It is worth noting that the [`<center/>` element has been deprecated since HTML4](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center) and is no longer recommended.  While it may be unlikely that support is dropped from browsers, it cannot be guaranteed to function in the future.

Comment: @AlexanderNied It has? Thanks for the information, I didn't actually know that

Answer (score 0):

HTML doesn't have a p6 Element. There is only p (paragraph) or h1 to h6 (Heading sizes).

It can be rewritten as a class of CSS, hence by selector `.` you can now select the class and edit it as per your requirement.

Comment: If want to be unique, use ID selector # and then edit it in CSS.